# QtCreator: breakpoints not working (in debug mode)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, breakpoints

I am running QtCreator 2.4.1 and certain breakpoints are skipped when I am working on a 'Plain c project' in the debug mod. I can reproduce the problem with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo()
{
  //statement 1
  //statement 2
  ...
  //End of function
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("String1!\n");
  printf("String2!\n");
  printf("String3!\n");
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line that prints "String1" in the main() function, the debugger just ignores it and goes on to execute all the below statements and run foo, but when I set the breakpoint anywhere inside function foo, the results are as expected(it does break). Can anyone explain/give fix to this behavior?
Additionally, I also noted that if I place the breakpoint in the main() after giving any scanf statement, it still works as expected..

Comment: What OS, compiler and what debugger are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found that this was a reported bug with qtcreator, they seem to have fixed this in the latest stable build.